# How to roll back Junits?

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, tdd

My project is pretty simple Java and Hibernate (- not Spring). 
When creating unit tests - Is there an easy way to roll back all the effects of the tests? or I have to do it manually?

I know that when using spring you can have the @Transactional annotation but I am not using Spring.

Comment: did you try the @After annotation

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is do start a transaction before each test and roll it back after each test. At least that's the way they do in Grails.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revert DB changes you should use a specific tool such as [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) where you can define your **dataset** and reset the status of the database for each single test.

You may clean the database either by defining your own `@teardown` or `@before` or by using DBUnit and annotate the methods with `@DataSet` specifying the dataset you wish to being used.